# Как определить что ввел пользователь, дробь или десятичное число?

Tags: c++

Программа должна писать ошибку если пользователь вводит дробь или десятичное число

```
int a;

if (int (a) == double (a)){

cout<<"error";

}
```

Например пользователь

- ввел число 3 программа его (пропускает)
- 3,2 то писала (ошибку)

Comment: Придётся получать данные как строку и анализировать

Comment: В какой локали у вас `3,2` - десятичная дробь?

Comment: a что если пользователь вводит строку?

Answer (score 1):

Для единичного случая, как вы описали:

```
cin >> a;
if (char(cin.peek()) == '.')  
    cerr  << "error\n";
```

Но я добавлю от себя сложность. Лучше заставим вводить до тех пор, пока не введено целое:

```
int a{};
while(true) {
    cin >> a;
    if (char(cin.peek()) == '.') {  //если после целого есть точка
        cerr  << "error\n";
        cin.ignore();         // пропускаем точку
        cin >> a;            // читаем дробную часть           
    }      
    else
        break;
}

cout << "a  == " << a;
```

Update:

Или если мы хотим число передать как аргумент функции:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void get_int(double d)
{
    int a{};
    char c = '#';
    stringstream stream;
    stream << d;
    stream >> a >> c;
    if (c != '#') {
        cerr << "error\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << a << endl;
}

int main()
{ 
    get_int(4.5);    // error
    get_int(8.3);    // error
    get_int(5);      // 5
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <сmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i;
    double d;
    cin >> d;
    i = d;
    if (abs(d - i) > 0.000001)
        cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот вариант - ввести `3.0000000000000000000001` :) - https://ideone.com/E2ZwlD Или, второй вариант - как хотел автор - `3,2` (проверьте сами)...

Comment: Опять же - после вашего исправления: https://ideone.com/hFuhc1 Понимаете, автор дал нечеткое ТЗ. При таком ТЗ результат - ХЗ...

Comment: да, с некорректным вводом не поможет

Comment: не не работает((

Comment: @leocoolguy0: Попробуй ввести 3.2

Comment: ты менял локаль в своей программе? если не менял то должно работать. Если ты поменял локаль `setlocale("Russian")` например, то должен вводить через запятую

Comment: да нет я знаю что нужно точку а не запятую я просто вам для понимание показал что это десятичная дробь и мне нужно написать при ней ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Маленько модифицировал версию от "Kto To":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int i;
    double d;
    string m;
    getline(cin,m);

    const char *p = m.c_str();
    i = stoi(p);
    d = atof(p);

    if (d!=i) 
        cout << "error" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Answer (score -1):

Получать строку и искать точку как в комментах советуется. Если есть, то дробное. Кажется, именно так действует анализатор компилятора, поэтому запись ".8" имеет смысл.
Можно предварительно заменить запятую на точку и потом анализировать. Или наоборот.